# RingCentral stops sending call notifications in sandbox after making lots of calls

Tags: notifications, ringcentral

I have integrated RingCentral in my project and I am using the sandbox account for testing and I am successfully receiving call notifications in my project but after making lots of calls the RingCentral stops sending notifications so I had to create another account.

I have created more than 5 accounts that has stopped sending notifications. Also in my call log I can see that before that call duration was 03:47 minutes but after that it becomes 07 seconds and call status shows Unknown.

Is there any limit in sending and receiving calls notifications in sandbox and if I switch to production would it solve the problem?

Can somebody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There are limits for sandbox accounts, but if you are successfully making calls, you should be receiving notifications. If this is the situation, please contact our support team at devsupport@ringcentral.com .

Comment: I can see in the call log that the status is Unknown and the call duration is 06 seconds. When i am able to receive notifications the call duration is up to 03 minutes and it shows the status Voicecall.